# Типизированный ArrayList через Spring

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте. Такая ситуация: я поднимаю через спринг бин, у которого есть поле `ArrayList<String>`. Могу я как-то сказать спрингу, что лист, который определен в конфиге, типизированный?

Comment: Чего вы хотите этим достичь?

Comment: В самом классе-бине лист объявлен типизированным. а в конфиге класс для этого листа прописан просто как ArrayList. то есть сеттер принимает в качестве параметра типизированный лист. Спринг сам сможет разрулить такую ситуацию ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно помнить, что типизированными типы бывают только на этапе компиляции. После этого они затираются ("type erasure") и во время выполнения определить тип нельзя. Другими словами, несмотря на то, что вы можете объявить поле как `ArrayList<String>`, во время выполнения его класс не будет ничем отличаться от `ArrayList<Integer>` - JVM будет просто безопасно кастовать элементы коллекции к необходимому типу (безопасно - потому что на этапе компиляции это уже было проверено). Так как Spring создает бины динамически во время выполнения, то и типизированных типов там просто нет.

Резюмируя - это нельзя сделать, потому что это невозможно ввиду реализации generics в Java.

Comment: yozh, ,большое спасибо за разъяснения. Учту